# Can't convert date time to python readable format

Tags: python, datetime

I have a range of date time as follows:

```
Date
2017-04-02 12:00 AM
2017-04-02 01:00 AM
2017-04-02 02:00 AM
2017-04-02 03:00 AM
2017-04-02 04:00 AM
2017-04-02 05:00 AM
2017-04-02 06:00 AM
2017-04-02 07:00 AM
2017-04-02 08:00 AM
2017-04-02 09:00 AM
2017-04-02 10:00 AM
```

I want to convert all of them into python date time  to plot it in x-axis.I used the following code:

```
dates=fire['Date']#copy date value in dataframe
x = dt.datetime.strptime('dates',"%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p").date()
```

But it gives me error as:

```
time data 'd' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p'
```

How can I convert all these dates into python readable dates?

Comment: Unquote the d var

Comment: unquote `d` for further info check [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov  I have removed d and edited the question. But, It is giving  me same error

Comment: `strptime('dates',...` is still in quotes

Comment: @Michal What should be there in quotes.Or should I unquote here. I am new to python. So  I just don't know too much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d` is a variable, so you need to remove the quotes:

```
x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,"%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p").date() for d in dates]
```

### Edit : reproducible example

Following the OP request, here's a reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd 
import datetime as dt 
from StringIO import StringIO 

data="""
Date
2017-04-02 12:00 AM
2017-04-02 01:00 AM
2017-04-02 02:00 AM
2017-04-02 03:00 AM
2017-04-02 04:00 AM
2017-04-02 05:00 AM
2017-04-02 06:00 AM
2017-04-02 07:00 AM
2017-04-02 08:00 AM
2017-04-02 09:00 AM
2017-04-02 10:00 AM
"""
# StringIO is used to simulate reading from a csv file
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
print(df.head()) 

dates = df['Date']
x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,"%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p").date() for d in dates]
print(x)
```

The output:

```
[datetime.date(2017, 4, 2), datetime.date(2017, 4, 2), datetime.date(2017, 4, 2), datetime.date(2017, 4, 2), datetime.date(2017, 4, 2), datetime.date(2017, 4, 2), datetime.date(2017, 4, 2), datetime.date(2017, 4, 2), datetime.date(2017, 4, 2), datetime.date(2017, 4, 2), datetime.date(2017, 4, 2)]
```

On a side note, pandas can parse the dates for you as follows:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), parse_dates=['Date'])
```

The output:

```
                 Date
0 2017-04-02 00:00:00
1 2017-04-02 01:00:00
2 2017-04-02 02:00:00
3 2017-04-02 03:00:00
4 2017-04-02 04:00:00
```

Comment: @MalaPokhrel check the edit, I added a reproducible example.

Comment: @MalaPokhrel use `dt.datetime.strptime(d,"%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p")` instead of `dt.datetime.strptime(d,"%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p").date()`